# Android Karaoke-like : Updating GUI from MediaPlayer.currentPosition()

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm making some kind of "karaoke" android apps
So, basically, I have some TextViews and I want to change the text color programmatically while playing audio.

TextViews have the "begin_time" and "end_time" attributes which relates to the position in the audio file

Playing audio, and gathering informations about that is easy with MediaController

So, now I'm trying to change the color dynamically ... I tried with a separate thread and many other ways, but I always stuck with the same issue

> " android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. "

I tried to learn more about that, and what I learned is that everything related with the UI has to be done in the UI Thread.
Most of people use handlers to perform GUI update in background thread. But I didn't made this damn thing worked out ... So any suggestion about handlers and how they work is welcome.

Anyways, why not using AsyncTask ? 
Quote from the "Processes and Threads dev' guide"

> " Perhaps the best solution, though, is to extend the AsyncTask class,
>   which simplifies the execution of worker thread tasks that need to
>   interact with the UI. "

Actually, I'm using this AsyncTask, but it doesn't "simplifies" threading

Or Maybe they're is an other solution for GUI update from time event ?

---

Well, in fact, i don't want to make "just a karaoke" Textview have to be clickable, so when the user click on a word, the audio goes to that position in audio, and textview color have to change dynamically

So, I thought about using Animation for smooth color changing. Or maybe TransitionDrawable, but it use layers and canvas.

I also find out this, with ForegroundColorSpan:

```
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper");            
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 1, 13, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
TextView tv = new TextView(context).setText(WordtoSpan);
```

But not sure it will be dynamic enough due to calculation of the end of the ForegroundColorSpan.

So considering using only TextView, what is the best way to achieve dynamic textview color changing (with those solutions, or any other)?

---

Second edit

Well, i'm almost done with this project ...
I am now able to color word dynamically over time, but the problem is that it's not synchronized with audio.

i.e :
let's take a sentence like "hello, my name is john and i'm late for my job"
If audio is playing [i'm] the colored text is [job]

So, it's just a synchronization problem, but i'm facing it for several weeks.

The text is organized into a linked list
elements of the linked list are Object (because i'm having both Word and Ponctuation class) but both have a begin and end position, corresponding to their relative position in audio in milliseconds.

so ... I have something like that :
Hello : begin = 0,        end = 1000
my     : begin = 1200, end = 1400
and so on ...

In the main activity now, I have a Runnable that deal with text coloration
And I also have 3 Object, previous_element, current_element, and next_element

At the begining of the runnable, the color of the previous_element is set back to White, so only the current word is colored.
Then, the current_element's color is set to Yellow, or whatever ...
Then, I check if next_element.getBegin() >= current position in audio
 ... If it is, that mean the current word is now over, so I change the current_element to next_element, and start over the process using Handler.post(MyRunnableThatDoesColoration)

So I'm not understanding where it's going wrong
If anyone one have a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

> " android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. "

This can be achieved by using runOnUIThread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Your UI Changing code HERE!
    }
});
```

If you see the karaoke as basic gui (textViews), I think it won't be dynamic enough. You should use `Android Canvas` or a `gameEngine` (Andengine..).

Comment: I used the runOnUiThread method ... but it show a black screen for some seconds, and after it display the result of the UI changes.
It's not dynamic over time. 

I want UI to be updated while the audio plays ...
for example, at position X of the audio, I want the first word to be yellow. And at position Y, the second becomes also yellow

Comment: Run on ui thread works perfectly for this kind of things. Maybe your problemcomes from elsewhere. And I repeat, you should definetly use Android canvas or a game engine for this kind of app.

Comment: will I be able to determinate which word has been clicked with a canva ?
I use custom textview because it's make possible to know which one has been clicked, get the different information of the word such as position in audio file and so on ...

But using canvas, and drawText() will create clickable and identifiable elements listening to onClick ?...

Comment: Not as easily as if you used Textviews but you can have the position of a click and then compute yourself if an element was clicked and wich.

Comment: I also watched other application of karaoke on the market,some managed to use textviews but seem a bit laggy on old device..

Comment: Could you please post a full example of a runOnUiThread() with Dynamic UI modification over time ?
Because I didn't manage do make this work.
And I don't know where's the trouble.

Comment: Coloration Part is solved, but i'm still having some trouble for the sync between Audio and current colored word corresponding to the audio ...