# Highlight a part of textview in android dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have to do a karaoke interface. I need to highlight a part of the text view from time to time. let's say 5 seconds. I have separated the lines by "\n". After 5 sec, I need to highlight the other sent of lines till it meets "\n".

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by "highlight". But applying a different style to a certain part of a string can be done using some form of Span, e.g. `BackgroundColorSpan` or `StyleSpan`. Google them to find out more on how to use them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324414/android-karaoke-like-updating-gui-from-mediaplayer-currentposition I meant something like this. Here the coloration part is what i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to highlight substring of String in textview:

1. Split String to substring.
2. Add Loop on substring array length.
3. Add delay in loop - Need to add text highlight login under this delay.

Please try below code:

```
    TextView  tvHighLightText = findViewById(R.id.tvHighLightText);
    String textStr = "In publishing and graphic design," +
            " \nLorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document" +
            " \nor a typeface without relying on meaningful content. " +
            "\n Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.";
    tvHighLightText.setText(textStr);
    String splitStr[] = textStr.split("\n");
    Log.e("splitStr---",""+splitStr.length);
    Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    for(int i = 0; i<splitStr.length; i++){
        int finalI = i;
        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Spannable spannableString = new SpannableString(textStr);
                int startingPosition = textStr.indexOf(splitStr[finalI]);
                int endingPosition = startingPosition + splitStr[finalI].length();
                // For highlight current selected Sub String
                spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.MAGENTA), startingPosition, endingPosition, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                // For de-colorize the part of a string that has been colorized before
                spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, startingPosition, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                tvHighLightText.setText(spannableString);
            }
        }, 5000 * i);
    }
```

You can change delay time according to your requirment.

**Edit:**

Add this code in handler under loop for de-colorize the part of a string that has been colorized before.

```
spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, startingPosition, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: It works real fine!! Thank you so much. Could you please tell me how we can incorporate in this code itself, in such a way that we could de-colorize the part of a string that has been colorized before. My aim is to have color in only one part of the string separated by "\n" at a time.

Comment: @SubithSY Please check edited answer.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of part of **textView** programmatically.
Like this.

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(text);
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Get the text from textView and give it to the SpannableString and set the index of text string which you want to change the color

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I have to put this color onto another set of text after 5 secs. Can you suggest any solution,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spannable String Builder` to get your desired output.

**Below is the code:**
First splilt the string which you need to highlight, For example you store it in a variable `highlightedText` so,

```
  String finalText = SpannableStringBuilder().append("NORMAL TEXT ").bold {
           append(
                highlightedText
            )
            };

// then set the text to textView
   textView.setText( finalText ) ;
```